# Why the address of node is not assigned to the self referrential pointer of structure?

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<malloc.h>

struct node
{
    int id;
    struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node NODE;
int main()
{
    NODE *hello;        
    hello=(NODE *) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    hello->id=5;
    printf("\nAfter malloc\n");
    printf("address of hello: %d ",hello);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Value of Id is: %d , Value of next is: %u\n",hello->id,hello->next);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to execute the above code, I got the following output.

Output:

> After Malloc
>
> address of hello: 16949264
>
> Value of Id is:5, value of next is: 0

My question is, why the value of hello is not assigned to next?

Comment: `hellos->next` is used uninitialized (undefined behaviour), and use `%p` to print the adress of a variable

Comment: Strictly speaking, `%p` is for printing `void*` data. Try using this: printf("%p", (void*)hello->next);`

Comment: Why would you expect it that way? `hello` is not `hello->next`

Comment: @MikeCAT, you are right, a cast to (void *) is required

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have a doubt, when will the memory will be allocated for structure at the time of declaring or when the variable is created for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why the address of structure and next is not same?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780459/why-the-address-of-structure-and-next-is-not-same)

Answer (score 0):

> why the value of hello is not assigned to next?

Why it should be? You've assigned the memory to `hello`, so it has a *value*. `next` is not allocated memory yet, so it does not show any *value*. (To be truthful, it is indeterminate).

Also, to print an address, you should be using the `%p` format specifier with `printf()` and cast the corresponding argument to `(void *)`.

Also, [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have a doubt, when will the memory will be allocated for structure at the time of declaring or when the variable is created for it?

Comment: @lokesh1729 the memory for the pointer variable is allocated, the memory to the pointer (to which it will point) needs to be allocated.

Comment: @lokesh1729 try printing `(void *)&(hello->next)` and see for yourself.

Comment: NODE *hi;
 printf("\nbefore malloc\n");
 printf("\naddress of node is: %p",(void *)hi);
 printf("\naddress of next is: %p",(void *)hi->next);

Comment: I got the output like this
before malloc

address of node is: 0x7ffda77a81b0
address of next is: 0x7ffda77aa470

here why the address of node and next is different, next should store the address of node

Answer (score 0):

`hello->next` is not `hello`, so the `value` of `hello` is not assigned to `hello->next`.

`hello->next` is not `hello->value`, either, so `hello->value` is not assigned to `hello->next`.