# Why the address of structure and next is not same?

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<malloc.h>

struct node
{
    int id;
    struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node NODE;
int main()
{
    NODE *hi;   
    printf("\nbefore malloc\n");
    printf("\naddress of node is: %p",hi);
    printf("\naddress of next is: %p",hi->next);
return 0;
}
```

The output is:

before malloc

address of node is: 0x7ffd37e99e90
address of next is: 0x7ffd37e9a470

Why both are not same?

Comment: You don't (m)allocate anything, `hi` points anywhere. Your code exhibits undefined behaviour by dereferencing `hi` (in `hi->next`).

Comment: Let's say int *a , where a points to a integer type, so, just like that, in the above code I defined NODE *hi, it should points struct node. Memory is already created for it, why mallocate again?

Comment: When you declare `int * a` you reserve memory for the pointer, but not what it points to. So, just like your `NODE * hi;`, you get memory for the pointer, but not the target so dereferencing it before you assign it is undefined behaviour. Declaring a pointer does not allocate memory for what it points to.

Comment: Understood... Thank you,

Comment: Mode struct node *next so it's the first member of the structure. The address of a structure and the first member of a structure is the same (probably even if the address is uninitialized). There may be an exception to this in C++ with virtual functions, (I've read that some internal data may precede the first declared member of a structure or class).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR

Your code provokes *Undefined Behavior*, as already mentioned in [Morlacke's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32780514/1928852). Other than that, it seems that you're having problems on understanding how pointers work. See references for tutorials.

---

### First, From your comments

When you say that there's memory allocated for `ip` in this case:

```
int i = 10;
int *ip;
ip = &i;
```

What happens is:

1. You declare an `int` variable called `i` and assign the value `10` to it. Here, the computer allocates memory for *this variable* on the stack. Say, at address `0x1000`. So now, address `0x1000` has content `10`.
2. Then you declare a pointer called `ip`, having type `int`. The computer allocates memory *for the pointer*. (This is important, see bellow for explanation). Your pointer is at address, say, `0x2000`.
3. When you assign `ip = &i`, you're assigning the **address of variable `i`** to variable `ip`. Now the **value** of variable `ip` (your pointer) is the address of `i`. `ip` doesn't hold the value `10` - `i` does. Think of this assignment as `ip = 0x1000` (*don't actually write this code*).
4. To get the value `10` using your pointer you'd have to do `*ip` - this is called dereferencing the pointer. When you do that, the computer will **access the contents of the address held by the pointer**, in this case, the computer will access the contents on the address of `i`, which is `10`. Think of it as: **`get the contents of address 0x1000`**.

Memory looks like this after that snippet of code:

```
VALUE    :   10    | 0x1000 |
VARIABLE :    i    |   ip   |
ADDRESS  :  0x1000 | 0x2000 |
```

### Pointers

Pointers are a special type of variable in C. You can think of pointers as typed variables that **hold addresses**. The space your computer allocates on the stack for pointers depends on your *architecture* - on `32bit` machines, pointers will take 4 bytes; on `64bit` machines pointers will take 8 bytes. That's the **only** memory your computer allocates for your pointers (**enough room to store an address**).

However, pointers hold memory addresses, so you can make it point to some block of memory... Like memory blocks returned from **[malloc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html)**.

---

So, with this in mind, lets see your code:

```
NODE *hi;   
printf("\nbefore malloc\n");
printf("\naddress of node is: %p",hi);
printf("\naddress of next is: %p",hi->next);
```

1. Declare a pointer to `NODE` called `hi`. Lets imagine this variable `hi` has address `0x1000`, and the **contents of that address** are arbitrary - you didn't initialize it, so it can be anything from zeroes to a **[ThunderCat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkhRj.png)**.
2. Then, when you print `hi` in your `printf` you're printing the contents of that address `0x1000`... But you don't know what's in there... It could be anything.
3. Then you dereference the `hi` variable. You tell the computer: **access the contents of the *ThunderCat* and print the value of variable `next`**. Now, I don't know if ThunderCats have variables inside of them, nor if they like to be accessed... so this is *Undefined Behavior*. And it's **bad!**

To fix that:

```
NODE *hi = malloc(sizeof NODE);
printf("&hi: %p\n", &hi);
printf(" hi: %p\n", hi);
```

Now you have a memory block of the size of your structure to hold some data. However, you still didn't initialize it, so accessing the contents of it is *still undefined behavior*.

To initialize it, you may do:

```
hi->id = 10;
hi->next = hi;
```

And now you may print anything you want. See this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int id;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node NODE;

int main(void)
{
    NODE *hi = malloc(sizeof(NODE));

    if (!hi) return 0;

    hi->id = 10;
    hi->next = hi;

    printf("Address of hi (&hi)   : %p\n", &hi);
    printf("Contents of hi        : %p\n", hi);
    printf("Address of next(&next): %p\n", &(hi->next));
    printf("Contents of next      : %p\n", hi->next);
    printf("Address of id         : %p\n", &(hi->id));
    printf("Contents of id        : %d\n", hi->id);

    free(hi);

    return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
$ ./draft
Address of hi (&hi)   : 0x7fffc463cb78
Contents of hi        : 0x125b010
Address of next(&next): 0x125b018
Contents of next      : 0x125b010
Address of id         : 0x125b010
Contents of id        : 10
```

The address of variable `hi` is one, and the **address to which it points to** is another. There are several things to notice on this output:

1. `hi` is on the stack. The block to which it points is on the heap.
2. The address of `id` is the same as the memory block (that's because it's the first element of the structure).
3. The address of `next` is 8 bytes from `id`, when it should be only 4(after all `int`s are only 4 bytes long) - this is due to memory alignment.
4. The contents of `next` is the same block pointed by `hi`.
5. The amount of memory "alloced" for the `hi` pointer itself is 8 bytes, as I'm working on a `64bit`. That's all the *room it has and needs*.
6. Always `free` after a `malloc`. Avoid [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)
7. Never write code like this for other purposes than learning.

*Note: When I say "memory alloced for the pointer" I mean the space the computer separates for it on the stack when the declaration happens after the [Stack Frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) setup.*

---

### References

- SO: [How Undefined is Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961067/how-undefined-is-undefined-behavior)
- SO: [Do I cast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)
- SO: [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)
- [Pointer Basics](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/106/)
- [Pointer Arithmetic](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html)
- [C - Memory Management](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_memory_management.htm)
- [Memory: Stack vs Heap](http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html)
- [Memory Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management)
- [The Lost Art of C Strucutre Packing](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/) will tell you about structures, alignment, packing, etc...

Comment: @Enzo Ferber Thank you for your explanation, I have a doubt, if we declare , 'int a;' then a is the variable of data type integer, 'int *p; p = &a;' means, p is pointing to a i.e. it stores the address of a. But, in case of structures, what it lead to confusion is, if we declare 'struct node', then what is node there? I thought that it is variable, so if i declare a pointer to it, then it directly points to it. But in general, if we declare 'struct node var1;' , then var1 is a variable, can you point out the difference between var1 and node in this case?

Comment: @lokesh1729 When you declare `struct node *np;`  you have a pointer to a variable of **type** `struct node`. This only allocates space for an address. When you do `struct node myNode;` you declare a variable of type `struct node` - this second method makes the computer reserve some space for the variable on the stack. If you do `struct node myNode; struct node *np; np = &myNode;` it is correct. However, you still need to initialize the variables on `myNode` in order to use it.

Comment: @lokesh1729 What might be confusing you is the type. `struct node` alone is a type, not a variable. In `struct node myNode`, `myNode` is a variable of **`type struct node`**, and in `struct node *np`, `np` is a variable of **`type pointer to struct node`**.

Answer (score 1):

You have no malloc here.
hi pointer points to something undefined.
hi->next the same.

About the question. Why they should be?

I think you do not understand pointers.

Comment: I am confusing between general pointers and a pointer to a structure.
int *a;

Comment: Here, a points to a integer type, just like I defined a pointer to struct node, so it should point to that structure and the memory is already created for it

Answer (score -1):

because next is a pointer type and it is pointing to 0x7ffd37e9a470.
if you print the address if next &(hi->next), you can see both hi and hi->next has a difference of 2 (because of int id is the first element).